# IndexOutOfRangeException when passing empty string array to WebMethod

Tags: ajax, arrays, webmethod, indexoutofboundsexception, string

Tried every combo I can think of: String.Empty, IsDBNull.

selectPONumber is passed to "ByVal selectPONumber() As String" from "selectPONumber: [' + JSON.stringify('') + ']"

The StackTrace point to the second line of this VB

**VB**

```
    If Not IsDBNull(selectPONumber) Then
        If selectPONumber.Length > 1 Then
            qry = qry + "and ("
            For u As Integer = 0 To selectPONumber.Length - 1
                If u <> selectPONumber.Length Then
                    qry = qry + "and B.PONumber = '" & selectPONumber(u) & "' or "
                Else
                    qry = qry + "and B.PONumber = '" & selectPONumber(u) & "'"
                End If
            Next
            qry = qry + ") "
        Else
            qry = qry + "and B.PONumber = '" & selectPONumber(0) & "' "
        End If
    End If
```

Many thanks in advance!

**Update**

Replaced all lengths with counts, and took tranceporter's advice.  Now, it gives the same error on the "for" line.  How did it make it past the If selectPONumber.Length > 1 ?

**Updated Code**

```
    If selectPONumber IsNot Nothing AndAlso selectPONumber.Count > 1 Then
            qry = qry + "and ("
            For u As Integer = 0 To (selectPONumber.Count - 1)
                If u <> selectPONumber.Count Then
                    qry = qry + "B.PONumber = '" & selectPONumber(u) & "' or "
                Else
                    qry = qry + "B.PONumber = '" & selectPONumber(u) & "'"
                End If
            Next
            qry = qry + ") "
    ElseIf selectPONumber(0) <> "" Then
        qry = qry + "and B.PONumber = '" & selectPONumber(0) & "' "
    End If
```

**Solution**

tranceporter's solution is correct.  I stupidly treated a regular string as an array elsewhere in my code.  It started pointing all over the rest of the function as indexoutofbounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this (unless you already have)

```
If selectPONumber IsNot Nothing Then
    If selectPONumber.Count > 0 Then
       qry = qry + "and ("
        For u As Integer = 0 To selectPONumber.Count - 1
            If u <> selectPONumber.Count Then
                qry = qry + "B.PONumber = '" & selectPONumber(u) & "' or "
            Else
                qry = qry + "B.PONumber = '" & selectPONumber(u) & "'"
            End If
        Next
        qry = qry + ") "
    Else
        qry = qry + "and B.PONumber = '" & selectPONumber(0) & "' "
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank-you, but now it's moved down to the "for" line.

Comment: just try seeing the count value of selectPONumber. What is it? Is the index 0 based on 1 based? so what happens when you try selectPONumber(1) instead of SelectPONumber(0)?

Comment: funny you should ask.  I outputted that value in JSON, and it says 1 for both length and count.  I wonder how it's getting past the .count > 1 test.  I'll see what happens if I try selectPONumber(1).  Again, thank-you very much.

Comment: Also, it might seems stupid, but AndAlso is a short circuit operator. Instead of having 2 nested if conditions, write one if statement like i showed above. Can you post your updated code in your question please?

Comment: Just found out the VB.NET arrays are 0 based. That was a noob suggestion :)

Comment: it's so weird.  i outputted selectPONumber.Count > 1 to JSON, and it returned false.

Comment: I think I jinx edited over your edit.  Would you mind posting again if different?

Comment: Just tried.  still no go.  wonder if it's a vb.net bug.  going to try to set a boolean outside first because when i outputted the test, it returned false

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17577/discussion-between-tranceporter-and-joe-coder-guy)